# VBA Selenium with Chrome - Upload a file to the WebPage

Tags: excel, vba, selenium

1. I am using `VBA` to automate `Chrome` to upload a file to a site, with the `button` of `File` type
2. I have no idea about uploading script in chrome

My current VBA:

```
Sub UploadFile()
    Dim bot As WebDriver
    Set bot = New WebDriver
    bot.Start "chrome"
    bot.Get "https://tutorialehtml.com/en/html-tutorial-upload-form/"

         '#continue script here please"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is any input field with attribute `type = 'file'` you can use the below code :

```
bot.FindElementByCss("input[type='file']").SendKeys "path of file"
```